# Failure data of high-k dielectrics

Tags: data, failure, dielectric

How I can get access to failure data of high-k dielectrics caused by tunneling (trap generation)? I need a dataset for my research. (if someone could help me with the data, his/her name will be mentioned in the acknowledgment part of my paper).

Comment: You could probably get some pretty good leads by contacting electroluminescent lamp manufacturers.

Comment: How do you distinguish tunneling failure, from other mechanisms?  (I know nothing about failures of dielectrics I'm just asking.)  I guess the first thing I would think of is trying to measure it myself... leakage current vs voltage (or whatever)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, actually the process is like this: When an electric current passes through dielectric layer,
defects gradually build up as time passes . As
more traps are formed, they start to overlap and link together and cause more traps to be appeared due to thermal damage and result in the formation of a conduction path and build a chain through which charge carries leak from the drain to source or vice versa (tunneling).

Comment: @EMFields, Thank you for your comment. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks, It sounds a bit like a percolation problem.  I guess there is almost always one "weak link" in the chain.  For tunneling are you expecting an exponential current increase with voltage, above some threshold?    Hey, are we talking about leakage in high K ceramic capacitors?